# Sort an array date wise

Tags: php

I have an array. now i want to sort this array by date.how?

my array

$details = $this->api_model->testw()

here mysql query return result array in $details.

i want to sort my array as date then want to show output json

after calculating my output shows in json.

```
"details":[

        {
            "id":"2",
            "score":"1256",
            "user_id":"5",
            "date":"2014-02-05 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "score":"100",
            "user_id":"6",
            "date":"2014-03-08 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"4",
            "score":"123",
            "user_id":"7",
            "date":"2014-03-04 00:00:00",


        },

    ]
```

i am trying with using ksort but not work

Comment: It's a json string & not an array. And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Read `json_decode` and `usort`

Comment: this is a job for usort - although looking at this data, not PHP

Comment: This looks like a JSON representation of your array. To decode it, you can use `json_decode()` as others have said. But before that, you'll have to "fix" the JSON-string. The current one isn't valid, as you can verify using an online linter, like JSONLint.com — [**this**](http://pastie.org/8918406) should work, though.

Comment: If it is from sql why not sort in the sql query?

Answer (score 4):

Use usort. The function transforms the date field in the array to a unix timestamp which can easily be compared to each other.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
array( "id" => 2, "date" => "2014-02-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 3, "date" => "2013-02-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 4, "date" => "2012-02-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 5, "date" => "2011-02-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 6, "date" => "2012-02-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 7, "date" => "2012-04-05 00:00:00"),
array( "id" => 8, "date" => "2018-02-05 00:00:00"));

usort($arr,function($a,$b)
  {
    $a = strtotime($a['date']);
    $b = strtotime($b['date']);
    //return $a - $b; //is possible too, but harder to understand
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
  }
);

print_r($arr);
```